# SQLServer2008が長時間アクセス無い場合スリープ(?)してしまう

Tags: sql-server

OS:Windows Server 2008 R2
Server:IIS 7.0

ASP.NET(VB)とMicrosoft SQLServer 2008でWebアプリケーションを構築しています。
去年にトラブルがあり、OSを再インストールすることとなり、環境が一度まっさらになりました。

それまでは、長時間アクセスが無くても普通にアプリケーションが動作しており、トラブルはありませんでした。
OS再インストール後、何も問題なく動作していたのですが、長時間アクセスしていないと、必ず一度、データベース接続のタイムアウトが発生し、その後問題なく接続ができる、という状況になっていることが分かりました。
SQL Server Management Studioでも、長時間SQLを実行していないと、SQLを実行したときにタイムアウトとなり、再接続が行われ、その後スムーズに動作します。

恐らく、SQLServerの設定で変更すべき部分があるのかと思いますが、SQLServer アイドル時間、などと探しても思うような資料が得られない状況となります。

ご存知の方おられましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

-2015/03/04 13:35
追記：接続コード

```html
<%@ import Namespace="Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Type" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ import Namespace="System.Security" %>
<%@ import NameSpace="System.Security.Cryptography" %>
<%
 Dim dbConnection as sqlconnection = new sqlconnection("Server=[ADDR];UID=[ID];PWD=[PASS];Database=[DBNAME];")
 Dim sql as String
 Dim result as Integer
 Dim cmd as sqlCommand
 Dim dbRead as sqlDataReader
 dbConnection.open() ' ここでタイムアウトエラー
%><!doctype html>
-中略-
<%
 dbConnection.close()
%>
```

-2015/03/30 追記
回答に追加を頂き、試してみたところ、まさにこれだという内容でした。
参考先サイトによると

```
sp_dboption DBNAME
```

として実行すると、 autoclose が含まれる場合があり、これがあると自動終了になるようです。
ですので、次のコマンドでこれを取り払います。

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME SET auto_close OFF
```

以上です。

Comment: SQLServer側の接続タイムアウトを長くすると状況は改善しますか？また、サーバ自体が省電力オプションでスリープするといったことはないでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
■タイムアウト　.　
SQL Server Management Studio > オブジェクトエクスプローラー > データベース右クリック > プロパティ > 接続　.　
項目の　.　
「リモートサーバー接続」のリモート接続タイムアウトが600秒、となっていることに気付きました。これを質問投稿後、0秒(タイムアウトなし)にして現在様子見となっております。　.　
　.　
恐らくこれのことかと思っておりますが違っていればすいません。　.　
●省電力オプション　.　
確認しましたが、モニタの電源のみ切る状態になっていましたが、その他HDDのスリープ等はしない設定となっておりました。　.

Comment: サーバ自体がスリープというわけではなさそうですね。タイムアウトについてですが、DBへの接続は`ADO.NET`でしょうか？[ADO.NETにおける3種類のタイムアウト - あかばね発 開発者日記](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Y-Ishii/20101221/1292941342) また、もし可能でしたらASP.NET側で接続時の例外を取得されると良いでしょう。よくある接続エラーについては[Troubleshooting Connectivity #4 - 接続エラーの調査方法 - Microsoft SQL Server Japan Support Team Blog - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsql/archive/2012/11/09/troubleshooting-connectivity-4.aspx)が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 接続方法名称はあまり詳しくなく申しわないのですが、コード側で「new sqlconnection("Server=[ADDR];UID=[ID];PWD=[PASS];Database=[DBNAME];")」として直接接続する方法や、WindowsのシステムメニューにあるODBCを介した方法「Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") . dbConnection.Open("DSN=[NAME];UID=[ID];PWD=[PASS]")」で接続するコードもあります。詳しくありがとうございます。

Comment: また、エラーとしましては、前者の方法で接続したもので確認しているのが
「dbConnection.open() 」の行でタイムアウトする、というのが100%でして、何らかの原因でデータベースがスリープしているのだろうという推測にっています。

Comment: あまり原因が見えてこなくて申し訳ありません。もしよろしければ、ASP.NETでの接続処理部分のコード(機密部分は適当に改変したもの)を質問文に含めていただくことは可能ですか？他の方にとっても有益な情報になると思います。

Comment: いえ、こちらこそお付き合いありがとうございます。
問題となっている部分は郵便番号検索するための簡単なコードでも起こっておりますので、一番簡単なものの一部伏せたものを貼らせていただきました。

Comment: 今のところタイムアウトエラーが確認できなくなりました。もしかしたら最初のタイムアウト設定600秒が原因だったかもしれません。

Comment: 本筋ではないかもしれませんが、`dbConnection.close()`の代わりに`dbConnection.dispose()`を呼ぶようにした方が良いでしょう。(`sqlconnection`の`dispose()`は内部で`close()`も呼んでくれます。)コネクションが枯渇することがあります。/ タイムアウト設定600秒は手元の環境でもそのままですので、原因ではないような気がしています。

Comment: close => dispose の件了解いたしました。 closeで良いものだと思っておりました。
>原因ではないような気がしています。>現在様子を見ていたのですが、Management Studio使用中に再接続が発生したため、確かに違うかもしれません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

データベースのプロパティに"自動終了"という項目があります。

[SQL Server 2008 ExpressEditionでのデータベースの"自動終了"オプション](http://kenichiro22.hatenablog.com/entry/20101116/1289901540)

当方にすぐ確認出来るSQL Server 2008 Expressが無かったので、直接確認できてませんが、上記URLのページだと設定変更出来ています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
確認したところ、まさにこれでした。

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 5):

Express Editionをお使いでしょうか。
Expressにのみ「アイドル時は積極的にメモリを開放しディスクに書き戻す」仕様があります。
これを設定で調整することはできず、解決するには上位のEditionに切り替えるしかありません。

[Understanding SQL Express behavior: Idle time resource usage, AUTO_CLOSE and User Instances](https://web.archive.org/web/20151120042057/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/02/22/sql-express-behaviors-idle-time-resources-usage-auto-close-and-user-instances.aspx)

接続タイムアウトを十分に長くするか、定期的なポーリングでアイドルからできるだけ復帰させるという緩和策をお勧めします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Expressでした。
もしかすると前任者も、タスクスケジュールでそのような設定をしていたかもしれません。
定期的にアクセスするようなプログラムを用意してみようと思います。

Answer (score 1):

現時点でできそうな事を書いてみます。
1つ目としては、例外を捕捉して詳しい情報を調べてみてはどうでしょうか。

```
Using dbConnection As New SqlConnection("Server=[ADDR];UID=[ID];PWD=[PASS];Database=[DBNAME];")
    Try
        dbConnection.open
    Catch ex As SqlException
        // ex.Message に原因が書いてあります
    End Try    
    // 実際の処理 (Try中に書いても良いですが例外が発生しないならここで)
End Using
```

(`Using`を使うことで、スコープを抜ける時に自動的に`dispose()`が呼ばれるようになります。必ず必要なわけではありませんが、より安全な書き方のため載せておきます。)
得られたエラーメッセージを元に、サーバー側の原因がわかるかもしれません。
cf. [Troubleshooting Connectivity #4 - 接続エラーの調査方法 - Microsoft SQL Server Japan Support Team Blog - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jpsql/troubleshooting-connectivity-4)

2つ目として、`Management Studio`で接続し、`オブジェクトエクスプローラ`内で該当DBのツリーを開き、`管理`→`SQL Serverログ`からDB側のログを直接見てみると詳しい情報が得られるかもしれません。

---

余談：あまり数少ない経験ですが

- サーバーが物理的に不調になってきている。
- 仮想サーバで動いていて、物理サーバの負荷が増大している
- 同じサーバ上にある別のDBの負荷が増大している

といった場合に、簡単なクエリでも接続タイムアウトが発生することはありました。

Comment: 度々のアドバイスありがとうございます。using、素晴らしいですね。そのような使い方知りませんでした。本ソース含め、今後そちらに改変を進めようと思います。勉強になりました。


なお、後者なのですが、質問に書いた「トラブル」というのが物理的なものでして、レンタルサーバー元にすべて新しいハードウェアに変えていただいたので、物理的には恐らく大丈夫かと思います。専用サーバー、CPUおよび利用状況モニタでも使用率が0ですので、下記の部分は今回の件に関しては可能性が低い、と思っています。

Expressエディションのため、もしかしたらもう一方の方に回答頂いた内容かもしれませんので、そちらを調べてみようと思っております。